# Random Boolean Generator with Percentages of Chance

Tags: java

I am trying to code something, and I want to use the Random class that Java already has to set something equal to true or false, but the result being affected by a percentage of chance.

For example, I want create a method that randomly generates if someone becomes sick or not. If vitamins are taken there is a 20% chance of sickness. If no vitamins are taken there is a 25% of sickness.

I did some research and I see that the Random class in the API does have a random boolean method in it, but should I be using that? And if so, how would I implement my percentages of chance?

I know I will need a test class to create a person object, and I know how to do that, but here is what I have. Not sure where to go from here.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SicknessTest {

    private boolean sickness;
    private boolean vitamin;

    public void takeVitamin()
    {
        vitamin = true;
    }

    public void getSick()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate a double and check if it's bigger than the value you want to compare with. `nextDouble()` returns a value between 0 and 1.0

```
Random rnd = new Random();

public void getSick()
{
   if (vitamin)
     sickness = rnd.nextDouble() <= 0.2;
   else
     sickness = rnd.nextDouble() <= 0.25;
 }
```

Comment: Works pretty fine but why not nextDouble()? Ever so slightly more accurate at the extremes.

Comment: @SeanOwen agreed.  I tried to run some quick benchmarks but haven't yet gotten a clear estimate of the severity of using float instead of double, but it's certainly an easy way to improve the accuracy of the test.

Comment: The code here could also be simplified to `sickness = rnd.nextDouble() <= (vitamin ? 0.2 : 0.25);` but that's just syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the target percentage, e.g., 35% chance of true, then generate a random integer between 0 and 99.  If it's < 35, then it's true.  Otherwise it's false.

Comment: I think this is less desirable than using nextDouble(). For example how do you do something with probability 1 in 10 billion this way? Int overflows.

Comment: On the other hand, as long as you're ok with integer percentages, this avoids the inaccuracies inherent in floating point math.  You'd want to call `rnd.nextInt(100)` as its upper bound is not part of the resulting range.

Comment: This was the simplicity I was going for.  The question seemed to be a CS101 style homework assignment and I didn't want to drag in a whole bunch of externalities.